# Celery : specify chain in chord header

Tags: django, celery

How to specify chain in chord header? Chain object has no method s/subtask.

```
chains = []
for format in allowed_formats.keys():
    chains.append(
           chain(
                 covert_audio_file.s(audio_file_instance=audio_file_instance),    
                 upload_audio.s(),
                 mark_ready.s(),
                ) )
chord(
      [c.s() for c in chains],
      body=delete_original_audio.s(audio_file_instance=audio_file_instance)
     ).apply_async()
```